# What is correct, "press the Start button" or "press start button"?

Tags: terminology, articles

If we take the letter case into account there are 4 variants:

1. press the Start button
2. press the start button
3. press Start button
4. press start button

I have seen all of the above on the Internet, so I am confused.

As you probably guessed it is for a technical manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a specific button, usually the article "the" is used.  However, for brevity sometimes the article is omitted.